# How to re apply for a UK vistors visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, new-zealand, south-african-citizens

I was wondering if someone can assist me if it is worth re applying and if I can do it on my own or if I need an advisor?
was anyone successful when re applying?

> reasons for refusal
>
> you have applied for a visa to visit the UK
>   in deciding whether you meet the requirements of appendix of the immigration rules for visitors I have considered.
>   your application and any additional relevant information you have provided with it
>
> - your immigration history
> - an interview with you
> - an interview with your sponsor
>
> the Decision
>
> i have refused your application for a visit visa because i am not satisfied that you meet the requirement of paragraphs v4.2 of the appendix rules for visitors because:
>
> you have applied for entry clearance to the UK for a period of 13 days, Under UK immigration rules, you must show that you qualify for a visa by explaining your own circumstances and the plans you have for the visit.
>
> you state that you are employed by burnard international and earn $3760NZD (Euro 1965.53 Oanda exchange rate 10/01/2019 and in support of your application you have provided a bank statement account number ending 371 whilst i am able to reconcile some payments i am unable to reconcile to total amount that you have declared in your application form. you state that during your 13 day trip you will personally spend $4000.00 Euro 2112.27, however your balance as of the 20 decemver 2018 was $3897.70 Euro 2058.25, but based on the information you have provided i am not satisfied that you have the funds available to cover the cost of your trip. In addition to this i note that you will be spending all of the funds in your account on a 13 day trip to the UK, which i do not find to proportionate to your economic circumstances.
>
> You have also stated that the main purpose of your trip to the UK is to attend the memorial service of your close friend however i am not satisfied that you have been able to demonstrate that a service is due to take place. in light of the information provided in support of your application.I am not satisfied that your circumstances in New Zealand coupled with your reasons for wishing to travel to the United Kingdom are such that you intend a genuine visit or that you would seek to leave the UK at the end of the limited period stated by you. furthermore i am not satisfied that the documents provided represent a true reflection of your financial. Your application is therefore refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) (c) and (e)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) Please have a look at the answer to this question, and if it does not cover your case edit the question to indicate specifically why.

Comment: What country are you a citizen of? Do you have legal residence in New Zealand?

Comment: I am from South Africa but have legal residence in New Zealand